# LaTeX IEEEtran Citation cite command does not accept page numbers

Tags: citing, natbib

I currently try to cite using IEEEtran with natbib and want to give page numbers in specific cases but it doesn't render properly.

My configs etc are as follows:

packages.tex:

```
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
```

example entry from my bibliography.bib file:

```
@book{Eckert,
url = {https://doi.org/10.1515/9783110563900 },
title = {IT-Sicherheit},
title = {Konzepte - Verfahren - Protokolle},
author = {Claudia Eckert},
publisher = {De Gruyter Oldenbourg},
address = {Berlin, Boston},
doi = {doi:10.1515/9783110563900 },
isbn = {9783110563900},
year = {2018},
lastchecked = {2023-01-06}
}
```

my main.tex file declares the following:

```
\setcitestyle{square}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
```

Whenever I use \cite{Eckert} it properly shows the number in brackets as it should be.
But in some cases as with books I sometimes want to also give the page number for very long sources such as [1, p. 234]

The documentation says, this is achievable by simply giving a parameter in brackets as follows:

```
\cite[p.~234]{Eckert}
```

Unfortunately this produces this output:

> [? ]p. 234]Eckert

Can somebody please help me? I googled for hours but couldn't find a solution that worked for me.

Comment: Are there compile errors associated with this? If you can provide the complete source (of a simplified example that reproduces the problem), and note any errors you are having trouble resolving, that might help.

Comment: Additional to the accepted answer: `natbib` also does not use a smaller font in the bibliography which is in violation of the `IEEEtran` format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments of `IEEEtran.cls` file:

> `IEEEtran.cls` creates hooks for the optional use of Donald Arseneau's `cite.sty` package.

So I suggest you use `cite.sty` instead of `natbib.sty`. We can easily find that in the reference section, the font size of `natbib.sty` is larger than `cite.sty`, which is incorrect. Therefore, when you use `IEEEtran.cls`, you need to use `cite.sty`.

```latex
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\usepackage{xurl}
\begin{document}
This is a reference cite~\cite[p.~234]{Eckert}.
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

```latex
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{xurl}
\begin{document}
This is a reference cite~\cite[p.~234]{Eckert}.
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]